# Is it appropriate to close "my app has crashed" questions as duplicates of a generic "how to diagnose crashes" question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've recently seen a [number of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197113/duplicates-of-unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped) closed as duplicates of questions which explain general debug procedures (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/622391)). I usually encounter these duplicates when the original question contains insufficient information to diagnose the issue.

While it's true that the generic answer will be of use to the OP, is it correct to accept these duplicates? I often find myself hitting "Skip" or instead marking the question as "lacks sufficient information", as I'm concerned that a genuinely unique problem will remain unsolved due to its having been closed as a generic duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, they should not be closed as duplicates of [*Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/109702).

It is a perfectly good question and answer. But questions like [*Moving files from source to destination folder in android*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699398/109702) and [*Sqlite database size compare with local db size*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23719122/109702) (from your SEDE query) are hardly duplicates of it. It **may help** the OP of the example questions, but it **doesn't answer the question** (and most of the time the answers will be different). So by definition it's not a duplicate.

That doesn't mean the example questions shouldn't be closed for other reasons, they just shouldn't be closed for that reason.

Comment: So how do you prevent guess-answers from being posted until OP figures out the underlying issue and changes their question title and body entirely?

Comment: @code You can still close the question as too broad. When the OP edits the question it will automatically be moved to the reopen queue.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I prefer the "Off topic" option of _"because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example" ..._, since I feel that the OP is more likely to solve their own problem in the process of creating the minimal example.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, I do too, though it could be argued that the proposed canonical answer would help with that.

Comment: @PaulDraper, true, but I also feel that since the question will look superficially similar to its "duplicate", a reopen is less likely to succeed once a duplicate has been marked.